# Using mongoose to find by id and 10 subsequent objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to use Mongoose to find a object by _id then then the 10 preceding objects. I have found how to `sort` to order by date and the `find` function to find a specific object by id and the `limit` function to limit the results to 10, I just have not figured out how to find a specific object and the 9 objects that come after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is built on MongoDB, and the query syntax is essentially identical between the two. The [advanced queries page has a section on inequality matching.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%3C%2C%3C%3D%2C%3E%2C%3E%3D)

I haven't tested this, but since the MongoDB ID is a monotonically-increasing (but pseudo-random) integer, it should be possible to:

```
db.myCollection.find( { _id : { $gte : myIdVal } } ).limit(10);
```

Comment: It should, but remember to [read the query documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29), you probably want to use the "dot notation" and not the "sub-object notation".